# How to take key value pair value using org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser?

Tags: json

I am able to extract the Name value(Nungam Hwy) but I am not able to get the Time value(5:30AM) individually.

My code:

Following is my json which I read from my file.

```
private void convertJsonToSql() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    List<Time> times = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/bus/route125SaturdaySouthbound"));
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            String stopName = (String) jsonObj.get("Name");
            times = (List) jsonObj.get("Times");
            System.out.println("Stop name " + stopName);
            for (int j = 0; j < times.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Time" + times.get(j));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

[  
   {  
      "StopId":0,
      "Name":"Nungam Hwy",
      "Times":[  
         {  
            "Time":" 5:30AM",
            "RouteNumber":"12"
         },
         {  
            "Time":" 6:16AM",
            "RouteNumber":"12"
         }
}
]
```

Please someone help me...

Answer (score 0):

Using json-simple the following should work:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) config.get("Times");
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    JSONObject element = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Time " + element.get("Time"));      
}
```